# Should we have standing bounties?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

There [have been proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239527/do-not-expire-bounties-which-failed-to-attract-any-good-answers?) to [stop the bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239261/why-do-bounties-time-out) from [expiring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267021/request-new-function-standing-bounty). On meta.SE these have been received rather badly, but would be most likely [welcome here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3539/what-would-be-good-place-to-list-unresolved-bounties), as offering rewards for unsolved problems has a great tradition in mathematics, so I'm proposing to have this feature. (In case you wonder, apparently the developers monitor the meta of each site for feature-requests, so if it has a positive feedback here, it has a chance to be implemented once.)

To summarize some discussion, the main counter-argument was that such questions would occupy the feature tab for too long. I see no reason at all why the bounties couldn't be kept while removing the questions from the featured tab (possibly creating an old-bounty tab).

User [yo' said that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239268/273424) standing bounties might cause people never awarding the bounties. While I don't think this would be an issue, it could also be countered in several ways. For example, after the first 7 days, you could be offered to pay 100 more reps to keep the bounty (in the old-bounty tab), and if you ever award the bounty, you would get the 100 reps back (or optionally you could also claim it back by removing the bounty).

If you don't support this feature, I would be very interested to know why and discuss it.

Comment: No. There are people who use bounties to prevent their questions from being closed. Standing bounties would make a question remain open forever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Allow questions with bounties to be closed, then.

Comment: Here are some past posts related to Asaf Karagila's comments: [Why can't we close questions that have a bounty?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3229) and [Using bounty to prevent a question from being closed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2067).

Comment: @Emil: Yes, that would be nice to have.

Comment: As discussed in the links by Martin, questions to be closed with bounties can be flagged.

Comment: Flagging helps, sometimes. Not always.

Comment: On [codegolf.se] there is a separate post on meta for this purpose: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243).

Comment: And also on some other sites. [literature.se]: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1091), [puzzling.se]: [List of bounties with no deadlines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4399).

Answer (score 4):

There are several sites which use a separate post on meta for collecting "standing bounties" (is there some better terminology for them)?

Of course, if MO users want to consider a similar solution, it should be discussed first. But looking at other sites, to see how it works there, might certainly be useful for such discussion.

This answer is intended as a place to collect examples of other sites using this systems. It is a community wiki answer, do not hesitate to add other examples:

- Code Golf: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243)
- French: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785)
- Language Learning: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/629)
- Literature: [List of bounties with no deadline](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1091)
- Matter Modeling: [Community Bounty Board](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109)
- Puzzling: [List of bounties with no deadlines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4399)
- Science Fiction & Fantasy: [List of bounties with no deadlines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12517)

Comment: At least one of the questions on Puzzling is a notorious unsolved math problem, the magic square of squares.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It seems that finally there's a proper incentive to solve it, then!

Comment: @Asaf there's already a monetary reward on offer, http://www.multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquares.htm

Comment: @Gerry: But everyone knows that the *real* incentive to do math is fake internet points!