# Loophole to avoid closure: deletion + bounty?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, bounty

Recently a question was asked in a manner which seems somewhat inappropriate to me (independent of the value of the question). Specifically, it seems that:

- The OP asked the question and then immediately deleted it.
- Two days later, they undeleted it and immediately bountied it.

The reason this seems off to me is that effectively the question sprang into existence pre-bountied - which had the effect of preventing votes to close, if I understand the closure system correctly. Regardless of the details of this particular case (including whether this was actually the OP's intention) this seems like a loophole which could cause annoyance in the future.

My question is:

> Is this actually problematic? If so, would it be possible to modify the clock on bounty-setting so that a question has to exist *undeleted* for two days before being bountiable?

---

To clarify, I don't see any way this could be abused to gain reputation - the only point I possibly take issue with is the potential for sidestepping close votes.

Comment: Discussions on [meta.se] which seem related: [Starting a bounty immediately when a question becomes visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210486) and [Bounties and Delete 2 Days Requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266131).

Comment: This seems self limiting, since bounties spend down rep quickly. I don't think we need to worry about this until someone actually starts abusing it regularly.

Comment: Some previous posts on this meta related to closing and bounties: [Using bounty to prevent a question from being closed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2067), [Why can't we close questions that have a bounty?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3229), [Nominate bountied question for closure](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4559).

Comment: a comment in a [linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210486/starting-a-bounty-immediately-when-a-question-becomes-visible) seems appropriate:  _"if someone did this to try to keep a poor quality question open all you'd need to do is flag the question and a mod would refund the bounty and close the question."_ I also note that the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383579/which-great-mathematicians-were-also-historians-of-mathematics) that prompted the post here on meta was reasonably well received, not of the type that would require moderator intervention, I think.

Comment: To asses whether this is actually a problem, it might be useful to have some data. I have posted at least some queries showing questions which were both undeleted and bountied [in the MO chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/bounty-after-undeleting). (Although those queries can certainly be improved in various ways.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see a question that seems off-topic or inappropriate for MathOverflow, but protected from close votes by a bounty, please flag for moderator attention.  We can remove the bounty, and in obviously bad cases, close the question immediately.  More generally, if you think a bounty is being offered in bad faith, or in violation of reasonable norms, please let us know.

The [question under consideration](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383579/which-great-mathematicians-were-also-historians-of-mathematics) seems to be a reasonable one, although the last half seems to be unnecessary text that can be safely removed.

I don't see a long term problem with this particular loophole - people who use it repeatedly will get noticed.